# Tell F# that reraise returns no value

Tags: exception, f#, rethrow

How do I help the F# compiler interpret re-throwing an exception as having no return value?

For example, consider wrapping an operation to log the exception:

```
let doDivision() =
    try
        2 / 0
    with ex ->
        log ex
        reraise
```

The compiler reports this error for `reraise`:

> This expression was expected to have type `int` but here has type `unit -> 'a`

Comment: It can't have "no return value", because then the `try` and `with` branches would have different types. It needs to have the same return type as the `try` branch, namely `int`. This is what the compiler tells you by "_this expression was expected to have type int_".

Comment: If I understand it correctly, reraise returns `'T`, which becomes `int` to match the `try` expression.

Comment: Exactly........

Comment: `unit -> 'a` is the type of a function, that takes no argument (unit, `()`). With this, you can easily guess that you forgot to call the function.
Return value is `'a`, aka anything, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"reraise" is a function.  You need to pass unit to it.

```
let doDivision() =
    try
        2 / 0
    with ex ->
        log ex
        reraise ()
```